# Websocket Reconnects every Page Load

Tags: websocket

The following code runs everytime a page is loaded. 
I wanted to ask if this means a new Socket is being created on each page load or if it sees there is already a second and leaves it at that.

Also is there a way to see websockets in chrome inspector?

```
var socket;     
try {
earInterval(websocketTrychCatTimeInterval);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every page (or tab) opened will always start a new websockets instance.

Comment: You can see the network traffic in the chrome inspector that will show you a 101 changing protocol request.